# Sylius - Implements Slugable and Timestampable in new entity

Tags: php, sylius

I'm trying to create a few entities with the new Sylius version (1.0).

I'm reading their docs but i'm getting a bit mad.

Got a new Entity `Book.php`.

This entity got three fields, **author**, **title** and **content**.

How can I use the Slugable and Timestampable on this entity to create two new fields on this entity using annotations?

I try out to create an Interface `BookInterface.php` that extends of Slugable and Timestampable interfaces, but obviously, Doctrine doesn't map the fields of interfaces.

**Book.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\SyliusBookBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Resource\Model\ResourceInterface;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Book
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="book")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\SyliusBookBundle\Repository\BookRepository")
 */
class Book implements ResourceInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sylius\Component\User\Model\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;
```

---

## SOLVED

Using Gedmo entity trait works perfectly.

`Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;`

Then use it on your entity class:

```
class Post implements ResourceInterface
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
```

Comment: I don't know Sylius but why don't you just write:
`/** @var \DateTime @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update") ... */ private $updated;` for timestamp, and 
`/** @var string @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"}) ... */ private $slug;` for slug?

Comment: Thanks for your response @lolmx but i try to learn about good practices with Sylius :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wouldn't be able to mix annotation with `TimestampableTrait` from Sylius. A much easier solution is to define your own trait or use the one provided by Gedmo.

Anyway, why do you want to mix annotations with code? Keeping mappings in a xml/yaml file splits the logic and make a code more understandable. Keeping database mappings inside the entity also violates a Single Responsible Principle (SOLID Principles).

Here you have [some reading about it](http://www.beabetterdeveloper.com/2013/12/an-annotation-nightmare.html).

PS. I was writing it, when you have resolved your problem. I will just leave it here, maybe somebody will find the link useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `Component/Product/Model/Product` it uses the `TimestampableTrait` and it uses the `SlugAwareInterface` (through the `ProductInterface`). These interfaces are stored in the `Component/Resource/Model/` folder

So use the trait, and extends the `SlugAwareInterface`. Then add the necessary slug functions. `getSlug() setSlug()`

```
Interface ProductInterface extends
    AttributeSubjectInterface,
    SlugAwareInterface,
    TimestampableInterface,
    ToggleableInterface,
    ProductTranslationInterface,
    AssociableInterface,
    CodeAwareInterface,
    TranslatableInterface,
    VariableInterface
{
```

Comment: Yes i saw it but Sylius uses timestampabletrait and map those fields in XML, its posible to map the createdAt and updatedAt fields in annotations?

Comment: I think the comment on your question is the correct answer for using annotations. The xml version uses <field name="createdAt" column="created_at" type="datetime">
            <gedmo:timestampable on="create"/>
        </field>

        <field name="updatedAt" column="updated_at" type="datetime" nullable="true">
            <gedmo:timestampable on="update"/>
        </field>

Comment: Yes, but for annotation i need to redefine the class variable and it throws an error: > Entity\Post and Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\Timestampable define the same property ($createdAt) in the composition of Entity\Book. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible

Comment: I found the solution, I added it on the question. Thanks to all!